Can't add rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms
I am trying to add rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms to my repros so I can pull a beta rpm down of Xvfb on my Linux RH 8.9.   See https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/xorg-x11-server-Xvfb/1.20.11-22.el8/x86_64/fd431d51/package.   The problem is, it’s not in the available list of repros for my subscription (subscription-manager list –available) but subscriptions page says "Red Hat Beta Access" is Active, so it should be an option.
This is how I tried to add rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms:
subscription-manager attach --pool=$(subscription-manager list --all --available --matches "Red Hat Beta Access" --pool-only)

and
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms
Error: 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.

subscription-manager list --available
No available subscription pools to list

So how do I add rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-beta-rpms?

Maybe this helps:  https://linuxconfig.org/enable-subscription-management-repositories-on-redhat-8-linux

Let’s start with the basics, provide the output of, subscription-manager list --available by editing your question

did command subscription-manager list --available and added it to question.

@Johnkerich - I assume you have a valid subscription to RHEL? If you don’t then that’s the first step.
